# Why buttons are less clickable in customize callout bubble for annotationview?

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

Here I have pasted link for code: http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/ In this code I have just added one simple button.but my button is hardly press. we have to press long time for its click event.Not sure why buttons are less clickable? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an issue with the size? Try increasing the size of the button (but keep the image centered and the same size) so the interaction area is bigger than it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your button bounds. They may be smaller then the frame.